# When to use java.* and jdk.* packages

Tags: java, java-11

I'm using IntelliJ and JDK 11. In the library packages, I see two types of package naming. `java.*` and `jdk.*` like shown in the below image:

[image]

The `jdk.*` packages have `sun.*` packages inside them. What does this mean to developers? Is the general advice to avoid using `jdk.*/sun.*` as written over here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html ?

Comment: Guessing here: The `jdk.*` packages seem related to the actual compiler of the jdk. I think it's best to follow the advice from the given oracle link. If you use anything else than `java.`, `javax.` or `org.` you might run into issues when running on a different jvm (e.g. graalvm)

Answer (score 5):

You are misreading: these are not packages, but modules.

You should use `java.*` modules and avoid `jdk.*` because their access/api are not guaranteed to be stable. `sun` (and `com.sun.*`) are mostly moved into `jdk.*` modules.

This all boils down to the [JEPs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/200):

> The modular structure of the JDK implements the following principles:
>
> - Standard modules, whose specifications are governed by the JCP, have names starting with the string "`java.`".
> - All other modules are merely part of the JDK, and have names starting with the string "`jdk.`".

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm interested in `jdk.crypto.cryptoki` module. Is it a good idea just use https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/ee526a2ea840aedb97b23538f9d624acbccebc97/src/jdk.crypto.cryptoki/share/classes and maintain it myself?

Comment: Try to use `java.*` module. And unless you are a maintainer, or wish to maintain, of this module... try to use `java.security.Provider`.